# We can assign a colour, red or blue, to the points of a plane so that there isn't a segment of same colour

Tags: plane-geometry

> Prove we can assign a colour, red or blue, to the points of a plane so
>   that there isn't a segment of same colour.

---

Comment: It's not the solution, because there's (many) lines through the origin that are all blue.

Comment: Do you mean, colour a point $(x,y)$ blue if both coordinates are rational? Then every point on the line $y=\sqrt2$ will be red.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colour a point $P$ red if the distance from $P$ to the origin is rational, blue otherwise. If $S$ is any straight line segment, the set of distances from points on $S$ to the origin is an interval of real numbers, so it contains both rational and irrational numbers; i.e., $S$ contains both red and blue points.

A monochromatic set for this coloring, if it is connected and has more than one point, must be a circle centered at the origin, or an arc of such a circle.